# url in browser auto add another `)`?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to return `imageUrl`,
and I check the console is right `url(../../../../assets/images/bottom/123.png)`
But I don't know why in browser, it add a `)` so that it can't find the image

```
function getImage(imageName) {
  const imagePath = '../../../../assets/images/bottom';
  const imageUrl = `url(${imagePath}/${imageName})`;
  console.log(imageUrl," --!!!!!!!!!!")
  return imageUrl
}

getImage('123.png') // url(../../../../assets/images/bottom/123.png)
```

html

```
<img src={ getImage('123.png') } />
```

chrome browser console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/images/bottom/123.png) 404 (Not Found)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `img src` you are supposed to have `../../../../assets/images/bottom/123.png`, not `url(../../../../assets/images/bottom/123.png)`. The parenthesis at the end (but nothing at the start) is the result of the browser trying to make sense out of nonsense. `url(...)` is CSS; you've mixed up the languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the answer, but I do believe

```
const imageUrl = `url(${imagePath}/${imageName})`;
```

is where your problem occurrs.
Try removing the ) at the end, so it becomes

```
const imageUrl = `url(${imagePath}/${imageName}`;
```

If I were you, I'd experiment with some things.